# What are the drawbacks of having unused classes left in a c++ project?

Tags: c++

Let's say I had a class called `foo` which performed some functionality that I found was better done by library `bar`.

Assuming I deleted all references and includes of `foo`, could it still cause inefficiency in run-time/compile-time and would I have to remove the code from the project, is what I did enough or is this compiler dependent.

Comment: If your linker can't see the abandoned files then they won't cause performance issues. It might however be a bit confusing when trying to maintain the code.

Comment: Code that you never call is infinitely efficient.  You don't say anything about the linker you use, but a good one removes dead code.  Not that it is easy to notice if it doesn't, L2 and L3 cache inefficiencies are pretty hard to see back.  The commonly available whole-program-optimization is also a good way to eliminate it completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still compile the file containing the unused code then yes, it will impact your compile time.

If you are building a library then the type will also be included, even if unused, so it will impact your library size.

Run time impact will be minimal, but not zero - the dynamic linker will still need to spend a few nanoseconds on your type when loading your library.

If you are building an executable, any decent compiler/linker should be able to eliminate the unused code, so the only impact is on build time.

Remove dead code. Let your version control system (git, cvs, whatever) remember it for posterity, but get it *out* of your project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should remove unused code from the project. The reason is not so much efficiency or code size (with any modern linker there will be no impact), but a phenomenon called 'Software Rot'.

If you have unused but available code inside your project, sooner or later someone will try to use it again, but since the code was not available and not maintained, the code will likely be outdated and might cause serious issues in production. Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot

And it is not an empty threat - a similar thing once eradicated the whole trading firm as they lost all their money due to a software bug related to software rot: https://dougseven.com/2014/04/17/knightmare-a-devops-cautionary-tale/

Comment: Tangential: I winced when I read that blog-post. I feel bad for the developer(s) who didn't implement that last server change.

Comment: @Rietty this story is not so much about developer, as it is about software rot :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the linker.

If programs in the build chain (compiler, linker, etc) can detect that any symbol is not being used, it can safely remove them.

Moreover, if the class is unused, then there is no way to tell it has been removed - so any proper linker will remove it anyway.